# What is the meaning of two imaginary units in Bicomplex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, quaternions

We know the number of the form w=a+bi+cj+dij; (where a,b,c,d are reals and i,j are independent imaginary units such that i^2=-1=j^2) is called bicomplex number.
My question is: How it is possible the units i and j are independent(or different) but i^2=-1=j^2 ?

Comment: By defining it that way.  Quaternions (*which you tagged this question as as well*) act similarly.  You have $i\cdot i = -1$ but $i\cdot j = k$, showing that $(i\cdot i)^2 = 1$ yet $(i\cdot j)^2 = -1$ which acts as an example showcasing that $i\neq j$.

Comment: This is really no different than asking why $(0,1,0,0)$ is considered different than $(0,0,1,0)$.  It should be obvious that they are different.  They may share many properties, but when equality between two vectors is defined as meaning each corresponding entry is equal between the vectors, there should be no doubt as to the fact that they are different.  The same is true here.

Comment: Well, $i$ and $j$ are primitive fourth roots of unity and so they don't need to be equal as there are 2 of them.